# What is the benefit of _lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock()?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I saw many case of the following construction:

```
try {}
finally { _lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock(); }
```

Like this:

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public void A<T>(Action<ICollection<T>> operation)
{
    try { }
    finally { _lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock(); }
    try
    {
        B(operation);
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
    }
}
```

But I don't understand what is going on? What is the profit?

Comment: [Use upgradeable mode when a thread usually accesses the resource that is protected by the ReaderWriterLockSlim in read mode, but may need to enter write mode if certain conditions are met.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In this case, there seems no use. A read lock would have been enough since there is no write action or write lock. (Or is there? The sample is incomplete then)

Comment: It looks like a hack against the dangers of aborting a thread.  A finally block has an execution guarantee, it cannot be interrupted by Thread.Abort().  Not so sure it is an entirely valid hack, there is still an opportunity for trouble between the first finally block and the second try.  Might be okay, it is a problem with the legacy x64 jitter because it inserts NOP instructions to align code.

Comment: The blanket advice you will *always* get at this site is to **never** use Thread.Abort().  When you don't then you can certainly change this code.